# I am trying to draw rotating square in WebGL but not getting it. plus I need to add a point light source

Tags: javascript, webgl

```
"use strict";

var canvas;
var gl;

var axis = 0;

var xAxis = 0;
var yAxis =1;
var zAxis = 2;

var theta = [0, 0, 0];


var thetaLoc;

var flag = true;

var numElements = 36;

var vertices = [
    vec3(-0.5, -0.5,  0.5),
    vec3(-0.5,  0.5,  0.5),
    vec3(0.5,  0.5,  0.5),
    vec3(0.5, -0.5,  0.5),
    vec3(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5),
    vec3(-0.5,  0.5, -0.5),
    vec3(0.5,  0.5, -0.5),
    vec3(0.5, -0.5, -0.5)
];

var vertexColors = [
    vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),  // black
    vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),  // red
    vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0),  // yellow
    vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0),  // green
    vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0),  // blue
    vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0),  // magenta
    vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0),  // white
    vec4(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)   // cyan
];

// indices of the 12 triangles that compose the cube
var indices = [
    1, 0, 3,
    3, 2, 1,
    2, 3, 7,
    7, 6, 2,
    3, 0, 4,
    4, 7, 3,
    6, 5, 1,
    1, 2, 6,
    4, 5, 6,
    6, 7, 4,
    5, 4, 0,
    0, 1, 5
];



window.onload = function init()
{
    // --------------- Cube --------------------------
    canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");
    gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2');
    if (!gl) alert("WebGL 2.0 isn't available");


    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width - 50, canvas.height - 50);
    gl.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers
    // Create a buffer object, initialise it, and associate it 
    // with the associated attribute variable in our vertex shader

    var programCube = initShaders(gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader");
    gl.useProgram(programCube);

    // array element buffer
    var iBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint8Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    // color array atrribute buffer
    var cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertexColors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    var colorLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(programCube, "aColor");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(colorLoc, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(colorLoc);

    // vertex array attribute buffer
    var vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    var positionLoc = gl.getAttribLocation( programCube, "aPosition");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLoc, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLoc );

    thetaLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(programCube, "uTheta");
    render();



    //event listeners for buttons
    document.getElementById( "xButton" ).onclick = function () {
        axis = xAxis;
    };
    document.getElementById( "yButton" ).onclick = function () {
        axis = yAxis;
    };
    document.getElementById( "zButton" ).onclick = function () {
        axis = zAxis;
    };
    document.getElementById("ButtonT").onclick = function(){flag = !flag;};



}

function render()
{
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    if(flag) theta[axis] += 2.0;
    gl.uniform3fv(thetaLoc, theta);

    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, numElements, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

still, need to add below

Need to set up the surface normals for the objects being shown on the scene.

Properly setting up different material properties for the objects being shown on the scene.

Properly showing two different light sources at fixed locations that areused to illustrate properly the objects on the scene, and can be turned on and off independently.

Properly setting up the lights above with an ambient light sourcecomponent that is used to illustrate properly the objects on the scene and can be turned from totally dark to intense brightness using a dialor a slider (from 0-total darkness to 100-total brightness, with a default somewhere in between.

Comment: I'm taking a large pepperoni with extra cheese, thanks!

Comment: This is arguably too large a topic. Someone may come along and add an example but lights in WebGL generally require knowing a whole bunch of stuff before that which your question suggests you don't yet have the knowledge and so that answer would likely be too short for you or too long for S.O. I'd suggest you read some articles on [lighting in webgl](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-lighting-point.html) and the 9 prerequists to that article.